# Java 7 | Can we download the applet JARs in parallel?

Tags: java, jar, parallel-processing, applet, download

Our Web application depends heavily on Java Applets. For each Java Applet we have multiple signed jar files that contain the applet class and the dependent classes. The number of these JARs can go upto 70-80 per applet.

Looking at the Java Console Logs, it seems that the JARs files are downloaded and processed one by one, in a typical sequential manner. This causes a delay in loading of an applet when the JRE cache is empty.

To overcome this, one of the options that we are considering is to download the JARs in parallel. The following [Race condition in parallel downloading of jars for applets and web-start](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=24ca0c1ebdaa56b65e5d2c2389b6?bug_id=6890389) bug discusses an issue with parallel download of JARs:

So, my queries are:

- Does JRE downloads applet JARs in parallel by default and the Java Console logs don't portray correct picture?
- If above is correct, then how to validate if JARs are being downloaded in parallel?
- If above is not correct, how we can download JARs in parallel? like some custom code approach or some flag for JRE.

Answer (score 0):

*Perhaps* it could be achieved by:

1. Deploying the applet using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).
2. Specifying the Jars as `lazy` download.
3. Starting a number of `Thread` instances, that..
4. Use the [`DownloadService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/javax/jnlp/DownloadService.html) (or related services) of the [JNLP API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/javaws/jnlp/index.html?javax/jnlp/ExtensionInstallerService.html).

OTOH, I suspect the real bottleneck is the bandwidth of the user's connection.  70-80 Jars seems enormous!

Have you considered obfuscating the code?  I often denounce the ability of obfuscation software to prevent people from stealing code (if they are really determined, nothing will stop them), but doing so can often compress standard Jars by a further 50-60%.

Another thing to look into is [Pack-200](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/pack200.html), which might also give benefits in dropping the size of the required download.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Let me explore this option for the feasibility. Regarding number of jar files, yes I agree this is large number but again ours is a legacy application. We had considered obfuscation for security as well as shrinking. However, this was dropped as we are moving away from Applets. Thanks

Comment: Had a quick look at the [Migration Guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/applet-migration-139512.html). Our application uses java to js/js to java communication intensively. This feature is not supported by JNLP. The relevant excerpt is: _A Java Web Start application does not run within the web browser. So if your applet has any dependency on the browser (for example, Java to JavaScript / JavaScript to Java communications by means of the browser), the communication code will no longer work. The APIs that are affected include:_

Comment: Yes we are considering reducing the number of JARs. However, we were also exploring the possibility of downloading the JARs in parallel, so that combination of both (less number of jars + download in parallel) can help us to increase the Applet performance. Thanks and Regards